# Pattern matching on length using this GADT:

Tags: haskell

I've defined the following GADT:

```
data Vector v where
    Zero    :: Num a => Vector a
    Scalar  :: Num a => a -> Vector a
    Vector  :: Num a => [a] -> Vector [a]
    TVector :: Num a => [a] -> Vector [a]
```

If it's not obvious, I'm trying to implement a simple vector space. All vector spaces need vector addition, so I want to implement this by making `Vector` and `instance` of `Num`. In a vector space, it doesn't make sense to add vectors of different lengths, and this is something I would like to enforce. One way I thought to do it would be using guards:

```
instance Num (Vector v) where
    (Vector a) + (Vector b) | length a == length b =  
                                Vector $ zipWith (+) a b
                            | otherwise = 
                                error "Only add vectors with the same length."
```

There is nothing really wrong with this approach, but I feel like there has to be a way to do this with pattern matching. Perhaps one way to do it would be to define a new data type `VectorLength`, which would look something like this:

```
data Length l where
    AnyLength   :: Nat a => Length a
    FixedLength :: Nat a -> Length a
```

Then, a length component could be added to the `Vector` data type, something like this:

```
data Vector (Length l) v where
    Zero :: Num a => Vector AnyLength a
    -- ...
    Vector :: Num a => [a] -> Vector (length [a]) [a]
```

I know this isn't correct syntax, but this is the general idea I'm playing with. Finally, you could define addition to be

```
instance Num (Vector v) where
    (Vector l a) + (Vector l b) = Vector $ zipWith (+) a b
```

Is such a thing possible, or is there any other way to use pattern matching for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is something (in this instance confusingly) named a `Vector` as well. Generally, these are used in dependently typed languages where you'd write something like

```
data Vec (n :: Natural) a where
  Nil  :: Vec 0 a
  Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (n + 1) a
```

But that's far from valid Haskell (or really any language). Some very recent extensions to GHC are beginning to enable this kind of expression but they're not there yet.

You might be interested in [fixed-vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector) which does a best approximation of a fixed `Vector` available in relatively stable GHC. It uses a number of tricks between type families and continuations to create classes of fixed-size vectors.

Comment: Hmm. That is a little disappointing, but if Haskell doesn't have such functionality implemented then I guess there is nothing I can do. Thanks.

Comment: I really do recommend taking a look at fixed-vector, but none of these methods are too nice.

Comment: Note that as of GHC 7.8, something very close to this syntax should work. The declaration would work in GHC 7.6, but the arithmetic wouldn't do anything useful.

Comment: I can't rightfully recommend it until GHC headquarters starts to get confident about their numeric solver, but this is definitely true and exciting!

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the example in the other answer - this *nearly* works already in GHC 7.6:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures, TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

data Vector (n :: Nat) a where
    Nil  :: Vector 0 a
    Cons :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (n + 1) a
```

That code compiles fine, it just doesn't work quite the way you'd hope. Let's check it out in ghci:

```
*Main> :t Nil
Nil :: Vector 0 a
```

Good so far...

```
*Main> :t Cons "foo" Nil
Cons "foo" Nil :: Vector (0 + 1) [Char]
```

Well, that's a little odd...  Why does it say `(0 + 1)` instead of `1`?

```
*Main> :t Cons "foo" Nil :: Vector 1 String

<interactive>:1:1:
    Couldn't match type `0 + 1' with `1'
    Expected type: Vector 1 String
      Actual type: Vector (0 + 1) String
    In the return type of a call of `Cons'
    In the expression: Cons "foo" Nil :: Vector 1 String
```

Uh.  Oops.  That'd be why it says `(0 + 1)` instead of `1`.  It doesn't know that those are the same.  This will be fixed (at least this case will) in GHC 7.8, which is due out...  In a couple months, I think?